# Inject service in factory error : [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- ProjectService <- Project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I would like inject my service in my factory to use my factory in my controller :

**Controller**

```
app.home.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Project', function ($scope, $http, Project) {

    var project = new Project();

    $scope.refresh = function(){
        project.createTable();
    };

    $scope.refresh();

}]);
```

**Model (factory)**

```
app.project.factory('Project', function (ProjectService) {

    var Project = function (properties) {
        // Model
        this.file    = null;
        this.name      = null;
        this.path  = null;
        this.is_active = null;

        angular.extend(this, properties);
    };

    Project.prototype.setModel = function (obj) {
        angular.extend(this, obj);
    };

    Project.prototype.createTable = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return ProjectService.ok();
    };

    return Project;

});
```

**Service**

```
app.project.service('ProjectService', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    this.ok = function() {
      return 'all';  
    };

}]);
```

But I have an error :

> angular.min.js:13550 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- ProjectService <- Project

I don't see my error..

I tried to rename model/service it's the same error

In my index.html :

```
    <!--Project-->
    <script src="js/modules/project/project.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modules/project/model/project.model.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modules/project/service/project.service.js"></script>
```

Comment: Which scope are you expecting your `ProjectService` to receive? A service - unlike controllers and directives - doesn't have its own scope. Perhaps you wanted the `$rootScope` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you had injected `$scope` provider in `ProjectService` service.

> You can not inject `$scope` provider in service, basically it can be
>   available to inject in controller & directive link function only.

```
app.project.service('ProjectService', ['$http', function ($http) {
   var self = this;
    self.ok = function() {
      return 'all';  
    };
}]);
```